# Class not found even when in Jar in the classpath

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I am trying to deploy an application that is using Jackson, JUnit, and Commons-IO. I have the following Jars in my application's classpath:

```
commons-io-2.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar
log4j-api-2.4.1.jar
wsdiscovery-0.2.jar
jackson-core-2.7.0.jar
log4j-core-2.4.1.jar
```

This application works within my development environment, and I have deployed all of the above Jars with the main application jar. I can run the application without problems, but every time I try to use it I get the following failure:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at com.oncam.hware.app.OnvifApp.formatOutput(OnvifApp.java:356)
    at com.oncam.hware.app.OnvifApp.dispatchCommand(OnvifApp.java:271)
    at com.oncam.hware.app.OnvifApp.loopSocket(OnvifApp.java:130)
    at com.oncam.hware.app.OnvifApp.useSocket(OnvifApp.java:216)
    at com.oncam.hware.app.OnvifApp.main(OnvifApp.java:473)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

The ObjectMapper class is in the jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar file. Furthermore, I have no problems accessing the classes in the other jar files (including the JUnit jars!). For some reason, it is as if the classloader is loading every Jar except jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Someone please advise...

Comment: There must be a typo in your classpath. How do you run your program?

Comment: Use java -verbose to see where all classes are loaded from. Those errors also sometimes mask an error in the initializer or another dependency that could not be found like a super class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

It turns out that the environment I am using (Eclipse!) does not properly update the manifest file when you export your code to a JAR file. Without the proper manifest entries, the application cannot "find" the dependent jar files.

This is, in my opinion, a serious oversight on the part of the Eclipse folks -- especially when you have an application that depends on a lot of jar files. In order to make my application run, I had the following choices:

1. Create a script that runs the jvm and has a list of parameters pointing to every needed jar file, or:

2: Manually enter each required jar file into the Manifest file

To my knowledge, there is no way to automatically update the manifest file. This is a serious PITA (Pain In The A**)...

Anyway, sorry for bothering people about this problem. Hopefully, posting this answer will help others avoid similar problems...

Comment: Maven isn't the point. I had all of the jars the application depended on to run in the development environment. Unless Maven updates manifest files for you, it is irrelevant when you are deploying outside the environment. (Please note: how do you think I got all the dependent jars in the first place???)...