# [Java][Eclipse] NoClassDefFoundError/ClassNotFoundException >>> ObjectMapper

Tags: java, eclipse

Recent and amateur java developper, on Eclipse IDE, I have join the voluntary staff of a server game. I have a problem with the plugin of the server. It's normally link with our website, but the link seems break. The reason seems to be an "ObjectMapper" not found by the plugin :

```
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]: Exception in thread "Thread-8" 
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at main.java.com.naheulcraft.specific.Ressources.FeatureFunctions$AsynchronousAPISender$APISenderRunnable.run(FeatureFunctions.java:669)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[21:20:16] [Thread-8/WARN]:     ... 2 more
```

The following dependancy is in the pom.xml, and Maven seems detects it :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
```

There isn't error in the import :

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
[...]

private class APISenderRunnable implements Runnable
        {
            Map<String, String> params;
            APISenderRunnable(Map<String, String> params)
            {
                this.params = params;
            }

            public void run()
            {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String url = FeatureFunctions.BuildFullUrl(NCPlugin.API_URL, params);
                try
                {
                    array = mapper.readTree(new URL(url));
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("ERROR, URL BUILDING FAILED OR API IS DOWN.");
                }
            }
        }
```

But it don't work. I have try many propositions on the internet, as change the version, change the .classpath, use com.faster.xml.jackson.databind instead, add the .jar with buildpath > add external jars, clean and build the project... Without success.

This is the complete pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.naheulcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>specific</artifactId>
    <url>http://www.naheulcraft.com/</url>
    <build>
     <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>plugin.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>       
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <!--<repository>
        <id>bukkit-repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>-->
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope> 
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion> 
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion> 
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
             </exclusions> 
    </dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.google-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
            <version>snapshot-20080530</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <name>NaheulcraftFR-Specific</name>
    <version>1.10</version>
</project>
```

And the actual .classpath :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent_2/Desktop/Serveur test Spigot/bukkit.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent_2/Desktop/spigot-1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1577.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent_2/Desktop/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Florent_2/Desktop/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
Florent

P.S. : Sorry for my bad english, I'm french, I'm not english-speaker.
I write in english forums because I hope receive more help.

Comment: Evidently the code builds successfully, but the program complains about a missing class at runtime.  It follows that the needed class,  and probably one or more entire jars, is missing from the deployed class's *runtime* classpath.  That's a deployment problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: That's what I think as well, but I have no idea why the jar would be missing at runtime since it IS in the classpath (see above). Any idea how I might fix this?

Comment: The *runtime* classpath is not necessarily the same as the *build* classpath.  Fix the problem by either updating the runtime classpath or by copying the needed jar(s) into it.

Comment: I think I have found the runtime classpath (https://www.zupimages.net/up/18/03/4nw5.png) I tried to add the jar but there isn' change. However, I have found a topic with a similar problem if it's not the same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044107/class-not-found-even-when-in-jar-in-the-classpath). The person says it's necessary to create a script or edit the manifest file. I don't know how to do it, Could you guide me please ?

Comment: P.S. : org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper OR com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, this matter little. What does matter is to be able to use ObjectMapper and restore the link with the website.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. I installed m2Eclipse, I selected Run as > Maven Install. A jar-with-dependancies was generated in the target directory, including the missing ObjectMapper. I installed this on the server and this work, the link plugin>website is ok.
Thanks for your help.